# Conditional text color formatting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, colors, string-formatting

I'm looking to do some conditional formatting in my views.

So if I display a certain string returned from a field the text is colored red for example.  Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: Do you have sample mark-up for the kind of values you'd expect to see?

Comment: For example: <%= unit.unit_status %> which would display "In Service", "Out of Service" or 8 other statuses.  I'd like each one to display a different color in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your text before it hits your view to search the text for the string that you want to highlight. If you find the string, you can gsub it with the string wrapped in a span tag and a class. Then just apply the color with css.

```
def method
  keywords = ["dog"]
  @string = "My dog has fleas"
  keywords.each do |kw|
    @string.gsub!(kw, "<span class='highlight'>#{kw}</span>")
  end
end

# css
span.highlight {color: red}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, how would I pass it the value of let's say unit.status?  Would I do @string = unit.status

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do with unit.status. if unit.status is the string you are evaluating your matches on, then yes you would do what you mentioned above.

Comment: Here's what I came up with view: <td><div class="<%= set_status(unit.status) %>"><%= unit.status.try(:unit_status) %></div></td>  units_helper.rb module UnitsHelper
  def set_status(status)
    # Converts the status (if it's not nil) to a parameter version
    # "In Service" => "in-service"
    status.try(:unit_status).try(:parameterize)
  end
end
Then I styled each status in my stylesheet.  It came out a lot cleaner.